# Final step while integrating $\int\frac{dx}{x\sqrt{x^2+1}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, indefinite-integrals

I was solving a integration problem in which we have to integrate the following $$\int\frac{dx}{x\sqrt{x^2+1}}$$

I tried it lot , I think almost got the last step but the answer did not match. My try and the answer are as follows $$x=\frac1t,\quad dx=-\frac{dt}{t^2},$$ 
\begin{align}
\int\frac{dx}{x\sqrt{x^2+1}}&=-\int\frac{dt}{\sqrt{1+4t^2}}\\
&=-\frac12\int\frac{dt}{\sqrt{\frac14+t^2}}\\
&=-\ln\left[t+\sqrt{\frac14+t^2}\right]+c
\end{align} 
and the answer is $$\ln\left[\left(x+\frac12\right)+\sqrt{x^2+x+1}\right]+c.$$

Comment: The answer you were given appears to be wrong.

Comment: @smcc it might be

Comment: Yes indeed: that seems to be wrong, but differentiate it and check.

Comment: @DonAntonio how can i differentiate it

Comment: @user123733 You **have to know** perfectly well how to differentiate functions *before* you even begin with indefinite integrals (also known as anti-differentiation), otherwise it is going to be a very tough subject for you...

Comment: @DonAntonio but now can you help me

Comment: Why don't you first check the answer I wrote already? That for sure is correct unless I made a dirty mistake differentiating.

Comment: @DonAntonio yeah i got your answer but is the answer given by me is correct or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int\frac{dx}{x\sqrt{x^2+1}}$$
$$x=\frac{1}{t}$$
$$dx=-\frac{1}{t^2}dt$$
$$t^2dx=-dt$$
$$\int\frac{t^2}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}{dx}$$
$$\int\frac{-dt}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}$$

Answer (score 0):

From the beginning, let $x= 2\tan \theta$.  Then $dx = 2\sec^2\theta \, d\theta$, and $\sqrt{x^2+4}= \sqrt{4\tan^2\theta +4} =\sqrt{4\sec^2\theta} = 2\sec\theta.$

Then we have:
$$ \int\frac{dx}{x\sqrt{x^2+4}} = \int\frac{2\sec^2\theta\,d\theta}{2\tan\theta \cdot 2\sec\theta} = \dots$$

Answer (score 0):

An idea:

$$t^2=x^2+4\implies t\,dt=x\,dx\implies dx=\frac{t\,dt}{\sqrt{t^2-4}}\implies$$

$$\int\frac{dx}{x\sqrt{x^2+4}}=\int\frac{t\,dt}{\sqrt{t^2-4}}\cdot\frac1{\sqrt{t^2-4}\,t}=\int\frac{dt}{t^2-4}=\frac14\left(\int\frac1{t-2}dt-\int\frac1{t+2}dt\right)=$$

$$=\frac14\;\log\frac{t-2}{t+2}+C=\frac14\;\log\frac{\sqrt{x^2+4}-2}{\sqrt{x^2+4}+2}+C$$

I already checked the above indeed is the primitive of the original integrand. Now *you check* that what you say the answer is also is a primitive...or not.

Comment: What do you mean by primitive

Comment: @user123733 A function $\;F(x)\;$ is a primitive of a function $\;f(x)\;$ in some interval if $\;F'(x)=f(x)\;$ for all the values in that interval

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you're going from your second last to your last step.

A better substitution would be $x^2 + 4 = y^2$.

The integral becomes $\int \frac{1}{y^2 - 4}dy$, which is easily solvable by partial fractions. Remember to reverse the substitution at the end to get the integral in terms of $x$.

Comment: I have got the last step by taking t = tan b

Comment: Wouldn't it be $\sqrt{y^2-4}$ in the denominator?

Comment: @tilper No, not after the substitution is completed, including the element of integration.

Comment: I see what I did wrong now.  Put a pretend $x$ in the numerator.  I need to stop using this site/app immediately after waking up.